# Como modificar los archivos de la carpeta Release, siendo este usado por un usuario?

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, visual-studio-2017, microsoft

Actualmente quiero realizar un cambio desde mi visual studio y quiero pasar los cambios a la carpeta Release. Sucede que como esta en uso por un usuario del dominio no puedo aplicar el cambio que realice desde VStudio, por lo tanto tengo que esperar que finalice el proceso.

Existe alguna manera de Modificar la carpeta Release sin tener que sacar al usuario, aun los cambios no se vean reflejados, si no cuando el usuario vuelve y ejecute?

El proyecto esta desarrollado en wpf.

Comment: No deberías hacer que "Release" sea una carpeta compartida para tu red interna... copia los archivos a otra carpeta o usa Publicar y usa el asistente para colocar los archivos resultantes en la red.

Comment: Muchas Gracias , procedo con tu recomendación

Answer (score 0):

No es una buena practica y te lo digo porque trabajar con un escenario donde tienes mas clientes que deben de tu proyectos se podría complicar a la hora de hacer un deploy. Lo ideal es que utilices alguna especie de lanzador que te independice totalmente del fuente original que es quien debería actualizarse, de este modo el usuario cuando cierre la aplicación y vuelva abrir tomara la ultima versión.

Otra opción es utilizar ClickOne es muy practico y se ajusta muy bien a lo que quieres lograr, es muy fácil de utilizar y la curva de aprendizaje es muy rápida.